# Pickup that has same output despite how hard you hit the string

Tags: pick-ups

EDITS -> *

This might be a dumb question but I found nothing by googling

I am new to guitars and have only a strat i bought recently.

I was at a friend's house and tried to play one of his guitars but I immediately noticed that no matter how hard or soft I hit the string I would get pretty much the same output. *(meaning how loud it sounded)*

*Other guitars acted normal. Hard hit -> loud volume, soft hit -> quiet volume. But that v-cut just kept giving me the same volume. *

Now I understand that there is use for it but I would like to know how I can tell between "static" or "dynamic" pickups (I don't know the terminology) for any future purchase.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you determine the output level? Is there any sound processing involved? Compression? Overdrive/distortion?

Comment: It’s not necessarily the pickup. The amp could have added a lot of compression.

Comment: i mean how loud it sounds. His other guitars sounded normal but on that one it was like no matter what i did i would get the same volume level. His response was "EMG pickups tend to do that so it's easier to shred"

Comment: There's your answer. EMG generally makes active pickups, which are powered by batteries.

Comment: Was the amp. set the same for all the guitars?

Comment: @Tim Yeah i didn't touch it.

Comment: @DaveJacoby So an active pickup will result in constant levels of output for the most part?

Comment: @GeoKotze I don't think I've ever played one. But they have an internal pre-amp, and that, combined with a dirty amp, likely get that natural compression thing going. Shred techniques like legato, harmonica and tapping are quiet unless you have hot amps and pickups. Not sure you get a total removal of dynamics though.

Comment: High output pickups, active or not, tend to compress dynamics. Gain stages, compressors, etc have the same effect, but it may start from pickups.

Comment: Without more info it's hard to determine.  Every system has a limit to its ability to respond.  Acoustic guitars will poop out when you strum too hard.  It could be the quality of the pickups, how they are mounted (you can adjust the height), the strings, or the amp you where playing through.  It could also be a perception issue.  I'd hook the output jack up to an oscilloscope and really measure amplitude before deciding, your ears can deceive you.